# MacBook Pro shows folder with blinking question mark

Tags: macbook-pro

I was given a MacBook Pro 13″ A1278 laptop. While using it, a folder with a blinking question mark came up in the main screen. I could not find a way to get rid of it, so I formatted the HDD and completely erased every thing including the OS, but when I turn on the laptop, the folder and the blinking question mark is still there. I do not know the original OS. How do I fix that blinking icon?

Comment: The initial folder with the blinking question mark came up during boot time, I assume? Which OS X version have you been running before erasing the drive? How did you actually format the HD in the first place (as the system didn't boot anymore)?

Comment: I think it was OS X 7.3

Comment: I am not really sure,it must be OS X 7.3.1. I took laptop to a computer service center where I ask them to format the HD

Comment: I am not really sure, it must be OS X 7.3.1, I took the laptop to a service center, where I ask for them to format the HDD.